React Amplify signInWithRedirect Facebook requires multiple attempts before it works
I have a button to let users sign in with facebook, and the code looks like this:
async function handleSignInFB() {

    await signOut().catch((err) => console.log('Error signing out: ', err));
    try {
      //const user = await signIn({ provider: 'Facebook' });
      setSignInLoading(true);
      const user = await signInWithRedirect({ provider: 'Facebook' })
      //redirects tp / so no point to 
      return true;

    } catch (error) {
      setSignInLoading(false);
      console.log('error signing in via FB:', error.message);
      setLoginError(error.message);
      return false;
    }

}

Upon completion, the user is redirected back to the website, where I check for the authStatus like so:
const { user, route, authStatus } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user])

if the authStatus == 'authenticated', then it will show a logged in page.
However, first time users usually do not get an authenticated page after the redirect and often times they need to press the login button again or even several more times for it to work. I don't understand why this is the case, and why it usually happens more with first time users.
Any guesses?
